# Is the power of Tapasya the highest in Kali Yuga?

Tags: yuga, tapasya

According to a popular religious lecturer,

Krita or Satya yuga 10,000 years

Treta yuga 100 years

Dwapara yuga 1 year

Kali Yuga one day

are all said to yield the same benefit from Tapas.

What is the scriptural basis for this or similar gradations of the benefits  of tapas in the different ages?

Answer (score 1):

Vishnu Purana has one answer:

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc116063.html

> Being thus addressed by the Munis, Vyāsa smiled, and said to them, “Hear, excellent sages, why I uttered the words ‘Well done, well done.’ **The fruit of penance, of continence, of silent prayer, and the like, practised in the Krita age for ten years, in the Treta for one year, in the Dvāpara for a month, is obtained in the Kali age in a day and night**: therefore did I exclaim, ‘Excellent, excellent, is the Kali age!’